# Regular expression to replace all script src attributes

Tags: python, regex, django, pycharm

I need to refactor existing Django code, by using `{% static 'path/to/file' %}` tag. I think it's possible to use PyCharm feature "Replace in path" with regex option.

So, I need to replace my script tags, which now look like:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
```

To look like:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
```

Here is PyCharm "Replace in Path" window:

[image]

I think I should pass in "Text to find" something like `src="([^"]+)"`, but what should I pass in "Replace with", I can't understand.

Comment: Use `$1`.. and you will know how to modify it for expected results.. :)

Comment: I suppose `src="{% $1 %}"` should do the trick. Java regexp implementation [refers to $1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) the first capture group (in parentheses) as to `$1`, as oposed to `\1`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simplified version of your regex would be `src="(.+?)"`. Instead, you can use the following expression to match

```
src="/static/(.+?)"
```

And replace with

```
src="{% static '$1' %}"
```